# Push db file to Databases folder in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, filesystems, push

I wondered If it is possible to push db files into databases folder of an Android application either programatically or using any tool. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but not directly.

Typically a pre-built database would be included as an asset and copied to the databases folder for the package when the App is first run after installation.

If using this method then you should consider using [SQLiteAssethelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), as using this simplifies the process.

In one of my App's I introduced a back-restore that backed-up the database and could restore from the downloads folder. If need be I can copy a database from elsewhere into the downloads folder and restore from that within the App. However obviously such a database has to have the correct structure/schema to not result in errors. So that is another way but would be at the user's discretion to do.

Obviously data/data//databases is protected so that imposes restrictions on "Pushing" data directly into the folder.